# Reading a MemoryStream which contains multiple files

Tags: c#, memorystream

If I have a single MemoryStream of which I know I sent multiple files (example 5 files) to this MemoryStream. Is it possible to read from this MemoryStream and be able to break apart file by file?

My gut is telling me no since when we Read, we are reading byte by byte... Any help and a possible snippet would be great. I haven't been able to find anything on google or here :(

Comment: I figured that since it reads by bytes. So as I'm reading, if I decide to use a MemoryStream, I will need to place a delimiter or look to see how big the file is in order to determine where the files are on the MemoryStream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly, not if you don't delimit the files in some way or know the *exact* size of each file as it was put into the buffer.

You *can* use a compressed file such as a zip file to transfer multiple files instead.

Comment: well, whats happening is that I am unzipping files and placing them in a MemoryStream and I will use this MemoryStream later on for processing... So I'm guessing I would need to place a delimiter in the MemoryStream to indicate a different file

Comment: @NerdinTraining - Why can't you place the zip file in the memory stream and upzip the separate files each into its own memory stream when you need them?

Comment: I was trying to. but the files were beind multiplied when I was creating a MemoryStream. I switched to a FileStream and everything was working... Thats why I wanted to place everything inside a single MemoryStream

Answer (score 1):

A stream is just a line of bytes. If you put the files next to each other in the stream, you need to know how to separate them. That means you must know the length of the files, or you should have used some separator. Some (most) file types have a kind of header, but looking for this in an entire stream may not be waterproof either, since the header of a file could just as well be data in another file.

So, if you need to write files to such a stream, it is wise to add some extra information. For instance, start with a version number, then, write the size of the first file, write the file itself and then write the size of the next file, etc....

By starting with a version number, you can make alterations to this format. In the future you may decide you need to store the file name as well. In that case, you can increase version number, make up a new format, and still be able to read streams that you created earlier.

This is of course especially useful if you store these streams too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this yourself, what you would want to do is write in some sort of 'delimited' into the stream.  As you're reading, look for that delimited, and you'll know when you have hit a new file.

Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
 byte[] delimiter = System.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("++MyDelimited++");

 ms.Write(myFirstFile);
 ms.Write(delimiter);
 ms.Write(mySecondFile);

 ....

 int len;
 do {
    len = ms.ReadByte(buffer, lastOffest, delimiter.Length);
    if(buffer == delimiter)
    {
       // Close and open a new file stream
    }
    // Write buffer to output stream
 } while(len > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're sending them, you'll have to send them into the stream in such a way that you'll know how to pull them out. The most common way of doing this is to use a length specification. For example, to write the files to the stream:

- write an integer to the stream to indicate the number of files

Then for each file,

- write an integer (or a `long` if the files are large) to indicate the number of bytes in the file
- write the file

To read the files back,

- read an integer (`n`) to determine the number of files in the stream

Then, iterating `n` times,

- read an integer (or `long` if that's what you chose) to determine the number of bytes in the file
- read the file

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `IEnumerable<Stream>` instead.